# Download a file from a Link using Spyder ide

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I am new to Spyder IDE and I am trying to download a file from a URL. But Spyder is showing that " Cannot Download from https://...
When I do the same thing with jupyter notebook and vscode both works.
What is the problem Here?

```py
from owlready2 import *
onto=get_ontology("https://..)
list(onto.classes())
```

And the error is showing

```
  File "/home/sayantan/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/owlready2/namespace.py", line 895, in load
    except:  raise OwlReadyOntologyParsingError("Cannot download '%s'!" % f)

OwlReadyOntologyParsingError: Cannot download 'http://purl.org/ieee1872-owl/cora-bare'!
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can start by posting your code and the complete error message.

Comment: I have tried the same code with VSCode and Jupyter notebook and both of them works.

Comment: try running `import urllib.request;urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srfiorini/IEEE1872-owl/master/cora-bare.owl").getcode()` in spyder